# Create link for Compose mail - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I need to create a link on a mail ID(say x@company.com) which would take you to Compose mail of the logged in e-mail such as outlook account and put x@company.com in To:____
Any suggestions on how it can be done in Ruby on Rails using ActionMailer?

Comment: Something like [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/mail_to)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're to display this link on a website, a simple `mailto:` link would work. eg.

```
<a href="mailto:your@email.com">Email me</a>
```

You can as well provide the subject for it

```
<a href="mailto:your@email.com?subject=Contact Request from Website">...</a>
```

If you're trying to display this link inside another email, (ie. an automatic email sent from your website, for example, a transactional email) you can simply display the email address and rely on your email client (eg. Gmail, Outlook) to pick it up.

A few examples can be found [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/)